# Database for analyzing relationships between MMO players based on millions of Player->Player events?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, database

I play the game "Planetside 2", which provides a game-data REST API and a real-time websocket event-streaming service. I want to analyze relationships between groups of players based on their in-game actions. I have very little prior experience with databases, and don't know whether a relational, graph, or document-based database is most appropriate.

**Players are organized like this:**

```
Faction A                                             Faction B
    |____Outfit                                Outfit____|
    |       |____Player                 Player____|      |
    |       |____Player                 Player____|      |
    |                                                    |
    |____Outfit                                Outfit____|
            |____Player                 Player____|
            |____Player                 Player____|
```

There are 3 factions, but you get the idea. I want to examine the relationships between players and other players and outfits.

The vast majority of in-game events are of the form:

```
(Player1)-->(Action)-->(Player2)
```

Each event arrives in a JSON document with a form like this:

```
{
    "payload":{
            "amount":"",
            "character_id":"",
            "event_name":"GainExperience",      
            "experience_id":"",
            "loadout_id":"",
            "other_id":"",
            "timestamp":"",
            "world_id":"",
            "zone_id":""
    }
}
```

All the event payloads are flat, as above, but there is no guarantee the developers will not add or remove fields from the events. `GainExperience` is a particularly tricky type of event because there are nearly **400 different events** that reward experience. The `other_id` field identifies the recipient of the event, if any. For example, if someone revives another player, the revived player's `character_id` would be placed in `other_id`.

Most teamwork-based events are `GainExperiance` events.

---

#### The sorts of queries I want to do:

Most of the sorts of things I am interested would involve finding all occurrences of a particular event between members of different groups, then calculating and displaying statistics about those events. Maybe "intersections" is the right set-theory term for it?

#### What makes me uncertain about which type of database to use is this:

The sheer quantity of players, outfits, and events.

There are in-game "alerts", contests that last 2 hours. During a prime-time alert, there can be as many as:

- 1000+ simultaneous players in the Alert zone.
- 2000 total participants.
- 400-500 outfits represented by at least one member.
- 1-1.5M events delivered by the event stream, depending on which events are subscribed.
- The most active outfits may have as many as 100 participants in an alert.

That makes for some really scary numbers of possible player-player, player-outfit, and outfit-outfit relationships during a single alert. If I wanted to track more than individual 2-hour alerts, I can easily see these numbers causing my database to explode if I am not careful.

---

---

#### These are the databases I have looked at so far:

**MySQL:** This is what other developers who use the PS2 API use, and the server-side database is also some sort of SQL database, which is reflected in the way the API collections are structured.

My main concern is how to handle `GainedExperiance` events, because that single event type actually encompasses nearly 400 different events. I don't know if it would be best to leave it in a single large table, or attempt to split it into a bunch of tables by `experiance_id`. I also doubt that SQL is the best way to express the queries I am interested in.

**CouchDB:** The way it does map-reduce looks really interesting, but AFAIK it becomes really costly to change or add new views once you have a few million records in there. Saving the events as they stream in would be nice and trivial though.

**MongoDB:** Treating each event as a tiny document would certainly be convenient, but considering that each is so small and flat I don't think I would really be making use of MongoDB's strengths, and wonder if another DB is better suited to this.

**Neo4j:** A graph is great for representing relationships, but AFAIK they are designed more for a small number of edges between a large number of nodes, not a large number of edges between a (comparatively) small number of nodes. This would be millions of edges between thousands of nodes, which is a bit different than your typical "find friends of friends of friends" sort of examples you read about.

---

## TL;DR:

I want to look at the ways groups of players interact in an online game, particularly team-work. There is a significant quantity of data available, most of it in the form of actions between two players. I am using my own PC for the time being, and have basically no real experience working with databases. I am intending to use Nodejs.

**Which database would be the best tool for this job?**

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would go for classical RDBMS like PostgreSQL or MySQL. The amount you mention (1.5M events) is a piece of cake. I would probably try to store player-player, player-outfit and outfit-outfit events each into separate table.

Comment: All the events are player->player though. Player-outfit and outfit-outfit stats can only calculated by aggregating player->player events. If outfit A had 20 members and outfit B had 30, then there are 20*30=900 possible pairs of players. Combined, those players could have tens of thousands of events they were involved in, which then need reduced to only events involving one player from each outfit.

Answer (score 0):

you might look at "wamp" or "xamp" = windows or linux computer, with apache, mysql, and php.  there is a good amount of php apps out there open source and simply how to guides vs node.js  that might help ya.

if this was just a quick study to see info (school project) thing. anything might work.but somthing that actually stores all the data into database table/s, and in a single file is what ya looking at.   storing multi info in different files = ouch.